# multiple subquery need to change as join query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all I need a solution for this question here is my query look like it works.But takes too much time because of sub queries.Give an alternate query to this query

```
SELECT *
FROM  `room_types`
WHERE id
IN (SELECT capacity
      FROM rooms
       WHERE id
     IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT room_id
           FROM  `reservations`
         WHERE DATE(
         START ) >=  '2016-01-10'
          AND DATE(
         END ) <=  '2016-01-15'
         AND STATUS =  'CheckedOut'
        AND id
         IN (
             SELECT op_no
             FROM  `bills`
              WHERE billed =  'Yes'
            )
       )
 )
```

Comment: No table data, no background = no answer.  Can you clue us in to the logic of the query and provide sample data or at least table structure?

Comment: New sql developer with that query. Don't feel bad. I did that once.

Comment: Ok I am drawing that tables and stuck with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. First try without Database Schema !

```
   SELECT *
    FROM room_types rt
    JOIN rooms r ON r.capacity = rt.id
    JOIN reservations resa ON r.id = resa.room_id 
                           AND DATE(resa.start ) >=  '2016-01-10'
                           AND DATE(resa.end ) <=  '2016-01-15'
                           AND resa.status LIKE "CheckedOut"
    JOIN bills b ON resa.id = b.resa_id AND b.billed LIKE "Yes"
```

Notice that "rt", "r", "resa" and "b" are aliases for your tables

Comment: Thats very helpful it is really i needed

Comment: But some mistakes are in your answer

Comment: SELECT * FROM room_types rt JOIN rooms r ON r.capacity = rt.id JOIN reservations resa ON r.id = resa.room_id AND DATE(resa.start ) >= '2016-01-10' AND DATE(resa.end ) <= '2016-01-15' AND resa.status LIKE "CheckedOut" JOIN bills b ON resa.id = b.op_no AND b.billed LIKE "Yes"

Comment: Change your query as this i will accept your answer

Comment: Change done. Without DB schema I had to suppose links between tables as you know. I suppose now that room_types is more or less room size determination.Glad it helps

Answer (score 2):

As of your provided query, Try this:

```
    SELECT
            `room_types`.*
    FROM
            `room_types`
            INNER JOIN `rooms` ON (`room_types`.`id` = `rooms`.`id`)
            INNER JOIN `reservations` ON (`rooms`.`id` = `reservations`.`room_id`)
            INNER JOIN `bills` ON (`reservations`.`id` = `bills`.`op_no`)
    WHERE
            DATE(`reservations`.`START`) BETWEEN '2016-01-10' AND '2016-01-15' 
            AND `reservations`.`STATUS` = 'CheckedOut'
            AND `bills`.`billed` = 'Yes'
```

Also you can index columns which will make it more faster.

Comment: Using "*BETWEEN*" is cleaner than splitting WHERE clause in 2 : "<" ">"